# The sum-of-squares of the increments of an interval's partition

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $t \in \left(0,\infty\right)$ and, for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_1$, let $m_n \in \mathbb{N}_1$ and let $t^{(n)}_0, t^{(n)}_1, \dots, t^{(n)}_{m_n} \in \left[0, t\right]$ be such that $0 = t^{(n)}_0 \leq t^{(n)}_1 \leq \cdots \leq t^{(n)}_{m_n} = t$ and $\max \left\{t^{(n)}_k - t^{(n)}_{k - 1}\ :\mid\ k \in \left\{1, \dots, m_n\right\}\right\}< \frac{1}{n}$. For each $n \in \mathbb{N}_1$, define
$$
s_n := \sum_{k = 1}^{m_n}\left(t^{(n)}_k - t^{(n)}_{k - 1}\right)^2
$$
Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} s_n = 0$.

---

N.B.
This is a homework question. Just a hint, please.

Comment: $a_k^2 \leqslant a_k\cdot \max \{ a_k : 1 \leqslant k \leqslant m_n\}$

Comment: @DanielFischer: Got it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Daniel Fischer's hint,
$$
0 \leq s_n \leq \sum_{k = 1}^{m_n}\left[\left(t^{(n)}_k - t^{(n)}_{k - 1}\right)\underbrace{\max_{i \in \left\{1, \dots, m_n\right\}}\left(t^{(n)}_i - t^{(n)}_{i - 1}\right)}_{=: M_n}\right] = M_n\sum_{k = 1}^{m_n}\left(t^{(n)}_k - t^{(n)}_{k - 1}\right) = M_nt
$$

Since,by assumption, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} M_n = 0$, $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}s_n = 0$.